When I compile my program I get "path" is longer than filepath buffer
This is my first attempt to write a program in Swift using Xcode. I'm trying to create an iOS/iPad app that has eight buttons. When I compile the program (less than 300 lines), I get the error below. I am using xCode that was downloaded today on a Mac mini. I created the directory on my desktop for simplicity. I
'/Users/markrudnicki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RamBRAI-dxgpjfqixpqthlfnpxjmmvjmbsng/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/RamBRAI.app/embedded.mobileprovision' is longer than filepath buffer size (1025).
I used Product->Build For->Running (tried Testing, too). I cannot locate the upper level directory.

Looks like you created a bad path in your project. Maybe you have a link pointing back on itself. This isn't really an Xcode issue. Check your folder structure for your project.

Thanks! I cleared the Build Folder which has removed that error. Now, I have Link issues to resolve.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
